# Fade UINavigationBar while scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm currently attempting to add a functionality where the `UINavigationBar` is slowly faded in while the scroll to the bottom and is faded out when the user scrolls to the top. The current implementation below works but not well. The `UINavigationBar` is not faded in until the user is about 3/4 through the tableview. I have wondering if anyone had any. I could I start fading the bar when the user reaches a certain point within the tableview?

```
 override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let y = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if y > 160 {
      navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = false
      hideStatusBar = false
      setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
    if y < 80{
      hideStatusBar = true
      navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
      setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
let alpha = ((y * 200) / tableView.bounds.maxY) / 200 //**
    print(alpha)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = alpha
  }
```

Comment: I'm somewhat unclear on what is going wrong.  Are you saying that it only starts fading 3/4 of the way down but you want it to fade the whole way?

Comment: I want the fade in to start after the y pos. is >160 and the fade out the start after the y pos. is < 160